# External user unable to see more app in ms teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

When an external user logs in , they say only following options. they dont see pinned apps as well
I would like to pin apps for certain external users. is it possible to do so ?

[image]

but when i log in as external user form mobile device, i can see custom apps which i have deployed or pinned in teams admin center[image]

Answer (score 0):

External users cannot have app setup policies applied to them.

Comment: thanks treviry, but i see different behaviour when i login from mobile device. i updated th post. i see my custom apps from mobile device in teams

Comment: Yep, mobile does show up differently and may be a product bug as external users cannot have a setup policy associated with them.